# 1,q,a and z keys don’t seem to work work and it’s not the keyboard

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I have read a few of the other posts about keyboards not working but none seem to press on my issue.

I built a friend a new PC about 4 months ago. 3 months ago the <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>q</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>z</kbd> keys stopped working. She is not exactly computer literate but I had her try replacing the keyboard and the issue continued (I took one of these keyboards and tested it on a separate rig and it worked fine).

I did a reinstall of Windows 7 on the PC. Issue still happens. I tried going into the BIOS to test the keys there… They don’t even work in the BIOS. What options remain? Motherboard? If the BIOS does not even recognize the letters I am stuck thinking something is wrong with the motherboard.

I cannot think of any other possible reasons and would rather try every last other thing before replacing the M motherboard B.

Comment: is this in the ps2 port or usb port?  if usb try another port. if ps2 then try a usb port.  Does this happen in any usb port?

Comment: Before changing the motherboard try with all options of keyboard such as USB PS2 and the wireless keyboard. This probably would help u to locate the real cause of the problem.

Comment: I know you tested the keyboard in another comp to diagnose the keyboard ok But worth trying different keyboards too. It may be an odd never seen before  compatibility thing, worth checking

Comment: One keyboard was USB other was ps2 both had same issue both worked on other PC's. I do plan to try a wireless/bluetooth still.
EDIT: USB not USP...to much counter strike

Comment: how did you test qaz1 in the BIOS? if you can't really test in the BIOS you could try a linux live cd/usb.

Comment: I might as well try it. First thing I will do is get linux live on a usb and test the keyboard there. Any other ideas?

Comment: For the heck of it you should look at your motherboard's website to see if any newer firmware ever addressed the problem. Perhaps others had this issue before with your mobo. Just a thought.

Comment: try with another OS (like a live Linux USB) in the broken PC to see. Probably related to some virus or programs hooking the keyboard

Comment: "none seem to press on my issue." I see what you did there

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my laptop after changing out my CPU.

I had to uninstall keyboards in device manager, and reboot; keys started working afterwards. More than likely it was a driver problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem. My keys 1, q, a, z were working intermittently. I  uninstalled the HID keyboard driver from control panel and there was another driver already installed, so now the keys are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You'll never believe my solution to this tres frustrating problem! (and this was after trying everything BIOS-test, a wireless keyboard, crying!) now look... 1QAZ!! 1QAZ!!
the solution???....get a can of 'air duster' or compressed air in a can, attach the extended tube and give those keys a good blast then leave keyboard alone for a couple of hours and....Voila!! Good Luck

Comment: Seriously?   You had a keyboard *that **worked fine** on one computer* but had problems on another, and blasting it with compressed air made it start working on both computers?    You’re right — I have difficulty believing that.